# Stock ticker makes site load extremely long

Tags: javascript, php, joomla

I needed to build a stock ticker with spechips stocks, after a very long search I found [Simple PHP Stock Ticker and Javascript Marquee for valid XHTML](http://techblog.shanock.com/articles/9/simple-php-stock-ticker-and-javascript-marquee-for-valid-xhtml) whic after some tweaking and the right .htaccess file and all I managed to make it work, when it is by itself as a lone html file it's fine more or less but when I added it to joomla the page with the ticker take extremly long to load, I haven't added the "stockcache" directory yet so it doesn't actually load anything but still it takes long to laod.

here is the code (the standalone html file)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<title>stockticker</title>
<!--    <link rel="stylesheet" href="stockticker.css"> -->

<style type="text/css"> 
#marqueeborder {
color: #cccccc;
font-family:"Verdana", Monaco, monospace;
position:relative;
height:20px; 
overflow:hidden;
font-weight:bold;
font-size: 0.7em;
}
#marqueecontent {
position:absolute;
left:0px;
line-height:20px;
white-space:nowrap;
}
.stockbox {
margin:0 10px;
color: #000044;
}
.stockboxname {
color: #359ad2;
}

</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on     http://techblog.shanock.com

    // Set an initial scroll speed. This equates to the number of pixels shifted per         tick
var scrollspeed=3;
var pxptick=scrollspeed;
function startmarquee(){
    // Make a shortcut referencing our div with the content we want to scroll
    marqueediv=document.getElementById("marqueecontent");
    // Get the total width of our available scroll area
    marqueewidth=document.getElementById("marqueeborder").offsetWidth;
    // Get the width of the content we want to scroll
    contentwidth=marqueediv.offsetWidth;
    // Start the ticker at 50 milliseconds per tick, adjust this to suit your      preferences
    // Be warned, setting this lower has heavy impact on client-side CPU usage.     Be gentle.
    setInterval("scrollmarquee()",50);
    }
function scrollmarquee(){
    // Check position of the div, then shift it left by the set amount of     pixels.
        if (parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)>(contentwidth*(-1)))
        marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueediv.style.left)-pxptick+"px";
        // If it's at the end, move it back to the right.
    else
            marqueediv.style.left=parseInt(marqueewidth)+"px";
    }
    window.onload=startmarquee;
</script>

</head>


<body>


<div id="marqueeborder" onmouseover="pxptick=0" onmouseout="pxptick=scrollspeed">
<div id="marqueecontent">

<?

    // Original script by Walter Heitman Jr, first published on     http://techblog.shanock.com

    // List your stocks here, separated by commas, no spaces, in the order you want them     displayed:
    $stocks = "<!--stocks--    >KO,FB,AAPL,JPM,MSFT,GOOG,TWTR,VOD,SCGLF,VXX,SBRCY,SSNLF,IBN,WEBNF,<!--comodeties--    >GCV14.CMX<!--gold-->,SIZ13.CMX<!--silver-->,PLF14.NYM<!--platinum-->,CZ13.CBT<!--corn--    >,KCZ13.NYB<!--cofee-->,SBH14.NYB<!--sugar-->";

    // Function to copy a stock quote CSV from Yahoo to the local cache. CSV contains     symbol, price, and change
    function upsfile($stock) { copy("http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?    s=$stock&f=sl1c1&e=.csv","stockcache/".$stock.".csv"); }

    foreach ( explode(",", $stocks) as $stock ) {

        // Where the stock quote info file should be...
    $local_file = "stockcache/".$stock.".csv";

    // ...if it exists. If not, download it.
    if (!file_exists($local_file)) { upsfile($stock); }
    // Else,If it's out-of-date by 15 mins (900 seconds) or more, update it.
    elseif (filemtime($local_file) <= (time() - 900)) { upsfile($stock); }

    // Open the file, load our values into an array...
    $local_file = fopen ("stockcache/".$stock.".csv","r");
    $stock_info = fgetcsv ($local_file, 1000, ",");

    // ...format, and output them. I made the symbols into links to Yahoo's stock pages.
    echo "<span class=\"stockbox\"><span class=\"stockboxname\">".$stock_info[0]."</span> ".sprintf("%.2f",$stock_info[1])." <span style=\"";
    // Green prices for up, red for down
    if ($stock_info[2]>=0) { echo "color: #009900;\">&uarr;";   }
    elseif ($stock_info[2]<0) { echo "color: #ff0000;\">&darr;"; }
    echo sprintf("%.2f",abs($stock_info[2]))."</span></span>\n";
    // Done!
    fclose($local_file); 
}

?>

<!--
<span class="stockbox" style="font-size:0.6em">Quotes from <a     href="http://finance.yahoo.com/">Yahoo Finance</a></span>
-->
</div>
</div>

</body>
```

I put the script in the header.php and the php inside of an article

Comment: What is the problem? The serverside code, the clientside code? You need to narrow it down.

Comment: The ticker works but the page takes a lot of time to load

Comment: Take a look into the browser request timeline. That should make it more clear.

Comment: @Shmagic What takes the time to load? Something is the problem! You need to figure it out. Is it the server? Is it the DB, is it the amount of data, is it the widget. DEBUG!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is a bit of a mess:

```
$stocks = "<!--stocks--    >KO,FB,AAPL,JPM,MSFT,GOOG,TWTR,VOD,SCGLF,VXX,SBRCY,SSNLF,IBN,WEBNF,<!--comodeties--    >GCV14.CMX<!--gold-->,SIZ13.CMX<!--silver-->,PLF14.NYM<!--platinum-->,CZ13.CBT<!--corn--    >,KCZ13.NYB<!--cofee-->,SBH14.NYB<!--sugar-->";
```

You need to pull out the comments and change it to:

```
$stocks = "KO,FB,AAPL,JPM,MSFT,GOOG,TWTR,VOD,SCGLF,VXX,SBRCY,SSNLF,IBN,WEBNF,GCV14.CMX,SIZ13.CMX,PLF14.NYM,CZ13.CBT,KCZ13.NYB,SBH14.NYB";
```

Otherwise your code is going to try and pull, for example:

```
"<!--stocks--    >KO"
```

as the first stock quote from Yahoo Finance and likewise cause problems with gold, silver, platinum, corn, coffee and sugar quote pulls. PHP doesn't have

```
<!--
```

style quoting like HTML does. It uses /* */ style quotes.

After you've done that, it may work faster since Yahoo doesn't have to spend so much time trying to figure out what the heck you're wanting from them.

Comment: AWESOME! I removed the comments and I also created the directory "stockcache" (didn't exist before because I just wanted to try the code out)  Now works as it should